# Is there any way to populate activity property(checkList) value in runtime

Tags: c#, .net, elsa-workflows

I am trying to add an activity property value on runtime which depends on another activity. I have tried with `IRuntimeSelectListProvider` But it only works with Dropdown.

**In my case I need to populate "FormStructure" property when someone selects a "Form".**
Here is what I have tried.

```cs
public class FormSubmissionActivity : Activity, IActivityPropertyOptionsProvider, IRuntimeSelectListProvider
{
    private readonly Random _random;

    public FormSubmissionActivity()
    {
        _random = new Random();
    }

    [ActivityInput(
        UIHint = ActivityInputUIHints.Dropdown, 
        Hint = "Select a form", 
        OptionsProvider = typeof(FormSubmissionActivity)
        )]
    public string? Form { get; set; }

    [ActivityInput(
        UIHint = ActivityInputUIHints.CheckList,
        Category ="Form Structure",
        Hint = "Form Structure",
        OptionsProvider = typeof(FormSubmissionActivity),
        DependsOnEvents = new[] { "Form" },
        DependsOnValues = new[] { "Form" }
    )]
    public string FormStructure { get; set; }

    protected override IActivityExecutionResult OnExecute(ActivityExecutionContext context)
    {
        return Done();
    }


    public object GetOptions(PropertyInfo property)
    {
        return new RuntimeSelectListProviderSettings(GetType(),
        new CascadingDropDownContext(property.Name,
            property.GetCustomAttribute<ActivityInputAttribute>()!.DependsOnEvents!,
            property.GetCustomAttribute<ActivityInputAttribute>()!.DependsOnValues!
            , new Dictionary<string, string>(), new LoadForms(_random.Next(100))));
    }


    public ValueTask<SelectList> GetSelectListAsync(object? context = default, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {


        var cascadingDropDownContext = (CascadingDropDownContext)context!;
        var dependencyValues = cascadingDropDownContext.DepValues;

        switch (cascadingDropDownContext.Name)
        {
            case "Form":
                {
                    var list = new List<SelectListItem>()
                    {
                        new SelectListItem() {Text="Form", Value = "1"}
                    };
                    return new ValueTask<SelectList>(new SelectList(list));
                }
            case "FormStructure":
                {
                    var list = new List<SelectListItem>()
                    {
                        new SelectListItem() {Text="Child Form", Value = "11"}
                    };
                    return new ValueTask<SelectList>(new SelectList(list));
                }
            default:
                return new ValueTask<SelectList>();
        }
    }
}
public record LoadForms(int RandomNumber);
public record CascadingDropDownContext(string Name, string[] DependsOnEvent, string[] DependsOnValue, IDictionary<string, string> DepValues, object? Context);
```

The above code worked for dependent dropdown properties. When I changed the UIHint into `ActivityInputUIHints.CheckList`, it didn't trigger the `IRuntimeSelectListProvider`'s implementation.